# What does pointer do inside loop when initialized again and again?

Tags: c, loops, pointers, gcc, char

I'm working with STM32 uCs using the GNU ARM embedded toolchain. I'm trying to find out what happens when I initialize a pointer inside a loop. A pretty minimal example would be the following (partly pseudo code):

```
while(1)
{
    char* msg = "my message";
    transmit_via_uart(msg, strlen(msg));
    delay(1000);
}
```

Does the processor allocate new space for the string on the heap every time when the pointer `msg` is initialized again? Or does it overwrite the space the "old" pointer `msg` pointed to (no new space allocated)?

I know, that I could place the initializing line above the while loop, I'm just curious what happens, can't figure that out.

Thanks for a quick answer!
T.

EDIT: Sorry! Of course the compiler doesn't allocate anything... :)

Comment: The compiler doesn't allocate anything on the heap. Your program does when it calls `malloc` and friends. There is no `malloc` call, so no heap allocation. I recommend getting a decent book about C.

Comment: The only way to really know what happens is to compile the code and look at the assembly. The answer you get will only be valid for that specific compiler (including the options used) and the specific system used. You can for instance use https://godbolt.org/ to check this out. That said it's highly unlikely that you'll seen any memory allocation.

Comment: Pretty much all modern compilers will also optimize out the call to `strlen`, i.e. this function call will get compiled to `transmit_via_uart(address_of_string_literal, 10);`, as [seen here](https://godbolt.org/z/3l26bG). It would also be a good idea to write `const char* msg = "my message";` to ensure that your code doesn't attempt to mutate the string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C programs never allocate on the heap unless you explicitly use `malloc` family of functions.

The string literal `"my message"` is stored in ROM (likely in a section called `.rodata` or `.text` on most systems). It is allocated there upon program start-up.

The `msg` pointer merely points at that address in ROM. The pointer itself is allocated on the stack or in a CPU register.

The compiler is however smart enough to see that the address doesn't change even though you call this repeatedly in a loop. So it will most likely optimize away the variable `msg` and simply pass on to the function the raw, hard-coded ROM address where the string can be found.

You can place the initializing above the loop just fine, unless you are using a stone age, 30 years old C90 compiler.

---

As a side-note, a better way to write the code would have been:

```
char msg[] = "my message";
transmit_via_uart(msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
```

This way you can calculate the size of the string literal at compile-time, since it is constant and known. By using `strlen` you force a run-time calculation that the compiler may not be smart enough to optimize away.

Comment: When optimization is on the compiler will most likely remove the call to `strlen` anyway

Comment: Indeed, gcc and clang [optimize the call to `strlen`](https://godbolt.org/z/gCk_Bv) even with optimizations disabled, while MSVC will need `/O2`.

Comment: Using `sizeof` would require changing the declaration to `const char msg[] = "my message";`, otherwise you're getting the size of the pointer. Right?

Comment: Actually, there is nothing in the C standard that prevents local variables to be allocated on the heap. The standard does not even mention stack or heap. That is completely dependent on the implementation. I don't know about any system that works differently, but your claim is not necessarily true.

Comment: @Broman Heap allocation refers exclusively to objects of allocated storage duration. The standard is perfectly clear in regards of objects of allocated storage duration. There is plenty in the standard that prevents objects with allocated storage to somehow end up with automatic storage. So no, your comment isn't true.

Comment: Lundin, I am very surprised; you know better than this. (a) `sizeof(msg)` yields the size of `char *` since `msg` is `char *`. (b) “ROM” is a term for a kind of hardware, not for memory that is merely read-only by software (e.g., OS) enforcement or specification by the C standard. (c) “Heap” is [a kind of data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29), not properly a term for C’s pool of storage used for allocation…

Comment: … (d) Nothing in the C standard prevents an implementation from using a heap or its dynamic allocation subsystem for automatically allocated objects, as long as it does so automatically. (e) If the implementation chooses to use a CPU register for `msg`, it is generally not considered “allocation,” as the register is typically not reserved for a particular object but is merely used temporarily, intermingling that use of the register with others and using different registers at different times for the same object…

Comment: … (f) Moving the definition of `msg` to above the function broadens its scope, which increases exposure for error. A better solution to changing its lifetime, if that were desired, is to declare it `static`. (g) There is no reason to be explaining these things in terms of ROM or heap or CPU registers; explaining the lifetime of a string literal and of `msg` in terms of the concepts of the C standard is good, and ROM and heap and registers can be provided as supplementary information (that does not define the behavior but illuminates how implementations work).

Comment: @unwind Yeah it was a typo, fixed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ROM means Read Only Memory, nothing else. Hence the term `.rodata` which is not necessarily physical ROM. Heap is a data structure as well as the standard name for where allocated storage goes. Hence the term `.heap`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Comment: @Lundin: [ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory) is not defined solely by the literal meaning of its words any more than [White House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House) solely means a house that is white.

Answer (score 3):

> Does the compiler allocate new space for the string on the heap every
>   time when the pointer msg is initialized again? Or does it overwrite
>   the space the "old" pointer msg pointed to (no new space allocated)?

No. The string **literal** is known at compile time and hence the compiler is able to store it in a special section of the executable (usually the `.text`). When it needs it, the compiler can simply use a pointer to that piece of memory where the literal is stored. Ne need to perform any copy of the chars themselves.

This is what your code look like ([source here](https://godbolt.org/z/Qy06oi)) once compiled **with full optimization i.e. -O3**:

```
.LC0:
        .string "my message"
ff():
        sub     rsp, 8
.L2:
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    transmit_via_uart(char const*, int)
        mov     edi, 1000
        call    delay(unsigned int)
        jmp     .L2
```

The only thing that get initialized each loop (`.L02` section) is the pointer that gets the address of a known piece of memory at `.LC0` with the instruction: `mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0`.

No memory is allocated dynamically, and if you think about it, why bother doing it when all the info we need are known at compile time?

Comment: To me this doesn't look like a compilation of OPs code. Are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: @DavideSpataro: why would compiler optimize out the code?

Comment: You should probably mention that you changed the code... btw: how about `delay`

Comment: @DavideSpataro: you can [add an `extern`](https://godbolt.org/z/Xb36gy), c compiler runs before the linker anyway so it doesn't really care what you are doing. If the function is static and inline (like the one in your example), then of course it will remove the call altogether and be able to remove it if there are no global side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

In C all literal strings are really read-only arrays of characters, arrays including the null-terminator of course. When you get a pointer to such a string you get a pointer to its first element, the first character in the string.

Exactly where this array is stored is irrelevant, but there's typically only a single copy for each string literal.

As for the variable `msg` itself, it's very likely that the compiler allocates space for it when the function is called, together with all other local variables inside the function. The space for the variable could be uninitialized until you get to the loop. Then a good compiler would optimize it so the variable is initialized once only.

Comment: Re “there's typically only a single copy”: In C’s abstract computer, there must be only one copy, because the lifetime of a string literal is the entire execution of the program. It is one object; every time code reaches it, the same object is referenced. (Technically, the string literal in the source code is used to initialize an array of static storage duration, and it is that array which is referenced.)

Comment: Re “it's very likely that the compiler allocates space for it…”: Inside C’s abstract computer, space is definitely allocated each time the loop iterates (the lifetime is the block of the `while`, not the block of the function). Outside C’s abstract computer, it is likely no space is allocated for `msg`; the value passed to `transmit_via_uart` is likely constructed on the fly, using some form or mix of “load address,” “load/add immediate,” or similar instructions.

Answer (score -1):

> Does the processor allocate new space for the string on the heap every time when the pointer msg is initialized again?

A string literal in source code represents an array of characters that exists for the entire execution of the program. So space for it is provided when the program starts executing.

A typical way compilers do this is by putting the string in a constant-data section of the program.

> Or does it overwrite the space the "old" pointer msg pointed to (no new space allocated)?

In C semantics, every time the definition of `msg` is reached, an object named `msg` is created and is initialized to point to the array of characters.

In practice, good compilers will, especially when optimization is enabled, recognize this is not necessary to achieve the ultimate effects of your source code. For the call `transmit_via_uart(msg, strlen(msg));`, a good compiler will know both the value of `msg` (relative to the program section the string is stored in) and the value of `strlen(msg)`, and it will generate instructions to pass these values to `transmit_via_uart` without any need to use actual storage for a `msg` object.

One can make the meaning somewhat more evident to a compiler with:

```
while(1)
{
    static const char msg[] = "my message";
    transmit_via_uart(msg, sizeof msg - 1);
    delay(1000);
}
```

Declaring `msg` to be `static` and `const` explicitly tells the compiler that `msg` is a permanent array of unchanging data, and using `sizeof` tells the compiler the value is a fixed property of the object, not something that might be computed at run-time with `strlen` (although it is still technically a run-time expression, not a compile-time constant). A low-quality compiler that failed to optimize the original code might do better with this code.